# Coinciding linear operators on eigen values and eigen vectors.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If f and g are two linear operators in a vector space L over C, which are coinciding on all eigen values and eigen vectors does it mean f=g ?

Comment: You need to be careful what you mean by "coinciding on all eigenvalues and eigenvectors." If $f$ and $g$ are both diagonalizable and the eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs all match up (they need to match up in pairs, not just separately) then yes. If you don't require diagonalizability you can come up with counterexamples where the eigenvalues and eigenvectors match up but the generalized eigenvectors don't. *Please* don't get into the habit of assuming that linear operators are diagonalizable by default.

Comment: Could you please give some reference or more clarification that how diagonalizibilty guarantees f=g ? As i know diagonalizability of f and g means there exist a basis of L in which matrix of f and g are diagonal but how does it it connect with f=g with coinciding eigenvalues and eigen vectors?

Comment: Diagonalizability is equivalent to the existence of a basis of eigenvectors. If $f$ and $g$ are both diagonalizable and have the same eigenvectors then they can be simultaneously diagonalized. If they now in addition have the same eigenvalues attached to the same eigenvectors, they can be simultaneously diagonalized and the resulting diagonal matrices will be the same. So $f = g$.

Comment: Thank you. Its clear now !!